# java.util.ArrayList<T>

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

This is the implementation of java.util.Arrays.asList: ()

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<T>(a);
}
```

How can that compile?
I can't find a constructor for ArrayList, AbstractList or AbstractCollection that accepts a parameter like T... och T[].

Source code from:

```
java version "1.5.0_16"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_16-b06-284)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_16-133, mixed mode, sharing
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, I think I see the confusion now.

The `ArrayList` type in question is a nested type within the `Arrays` class - it's not `java.util.ArrayList`.

Comment: try to create a ArrayList with a T... arg or a T[]

Comment: Edited answer completely - hopefully that'll be more useful :)